# What is wrong with my if statements?

Tags: ruby, input, io

Working in Ruby, I'm trying to make it so when I enter a line of input it'll read it and match it with a few if statements.

```
input_stream = $stdin

input_stream.each_line do |line|  

  puts line

  if line == "a"
    puts "test 1"
  end
  if line == "b"
    puts "test 2"
  end
end
```

But when I run it, and enter in "a" or "b", this is the output

```
a
a
b
b
```

It recognizes that I entered a and b, and prints it back to me, but the if statements don't function as expected. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby maintains the newline when using `each_line`. The simplest solution is to drop it with `chomp`.

```
input_stream = $stdin

input_stream.each_line do |line|  
  line.chomp! # The new helpful line

  puts line

  if line == "a"
    puts "test 1"
  end
  if line == "b"
    puts "test 2"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Because line has \n character at the end if you write this it will work:

```
input_stream = $stdin

input_stream.each_line do |line|  

  puts line

  if line.chomp == "a"
    puts "test 1"
  end
  if line.chomp == "b"
    puts "test 2"
  end
end
```

Comment: That \n is not a symbol, it is a character.  In Ruby symbols look like :symbol with the colon in front of the name of the symbol.  In a Hash as a key we can have convenience of creating a symbol like this `key: value` where value in this case would be a variable (or possibly a method call) and the rest is Ruby history.